# Macro instruction object not available in data loader in my DE. Why?

Tags: soql, data-loader, macros

I had Created 1 macro with six instructions. In developer console I queried in query editor working fine see below.But in data loader there is not available Macro instruction object in Developer edition. Why this object not avilable in data loader.Could anybody explain on this.

SOQL:

```
select MacroId,createddate,Name,Operation,SortOrder,Target,ValueRecord,value,macro.name from MacroInstruction
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the **`Show all Salesforce Objects`** option when selecting  which object to work with:

[image: Show all Salesforce Objects]

Comment: I have already selected "Show all Salesforce objects". But did n't show